# Add logging to standalone Java application

Tags: java, log4j, classpath, log4j2

I have a single file Java program. It's not in a Maven package. I'd like to add some logging.

I've created a sample log4j2.xml file and have added the following to my Java file:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```

I think the only thing I need to do now is get the correct jar. First off I'm not sure which I need. Also, I believe this will have to be added to my classpath. Is this at compile time or run time and does the xml file also need to be on the classpath?

Comment: *"Is this at compile time or run time"* - both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up placing my `log4j2.xml` file to the root level, then created a lib folder and placed these jars inside:

`log4j-api-2.3.jar
 log4j-core-2.3.jar 
 log4j-jcl-2.3.jar 
 commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar 
 commons-logging-1.2.jar`

Finally, when running both javac and java I specified `lib/*` and `log4j2.xml` in the classpath.